# how to check whether MKL functions are involked when we enable EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL in EIGEN

Tags: c++, eigen, intel-mkl

I tried using IMKL through EIGEN by enabling  EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL flag. But when i compared the assembly code of 
1. MKL alone
2. enabling EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL using EIGEN

both are same...

Comment: Please show the exact expression you tried, not all operations are mapped to MKL.

Comment: #include<iostream> 
#define EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL
#include "Eigen/Dense"
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
int main()
{ MatrixXd m1,m2,m3;
m1<<1,2,3,4;
m2<<5,6,7,8;
m3=m1*m2.Transpose();
std::cout<<m3;
}


used
  Eigen 3.2.0
  intel mkl 11.2
  ubuntu 14.04 LTS
  intel core duo processor
  64 bit os

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to invoke IMKL functions from Eigen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080650/how-to-invoke-imkl-functions-from-eigen)

Comment: Hi, I have a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868462/no-speed-up-after-using-mkl-for-eigen?noredirect=1#comment68968960_40868462 . How did you solve your problem?