# how to invoke IMKL functions from Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, intel-mkl

```
#include<iostream>    
#define EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL    
#include"mkl.h"    
#include<Eigen/Dense>    

using Eigen::MatrixXd;    

int main() 
{    
    MatrixXd m1,m2,m3;    
    m1<<1,2,3,4;    
    m2<<5,6,7,8;    
    m3=m1*m2.Transpose();    
    std::cout<<m3;    
}
```

i used IMKL11.2
       Eigen 3.2.0
       ubuntu 14.04 LTS
       intel core duo processor
       64bit os
       g++ compiler

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html
 the link says that we can use IMKL from Eigen by defining the macro. But the following error pope up

in file included from Eigen/Core from Eigen/Dense from test.cpp 
  MKL_BLAS was not decleared in this scope

Comment: Thank you    but now it shows another error
Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU_MKL.h:36:45: fatal error: Eigen/src/Core/util/MKL_support.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Eigen/src/Core/util/MKL_support.h"

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in changeset [0cc8ceeb7dd1](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/0cc8ceeb7dd1) which is part of the latest stable release, namely [Eigen 3.2.6](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=News:Eigen_3.2.6_released!).